# Hierarchical Preferences in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table where I can have ratio for an item either at its own level or parent.
Example below.

```
Table1
   Level|Level Value|Ratio
   -----------------------
   ITEM | ITEM1     | 0.3
   ITEM | ITEM2     | 0.4
   CLASS| CLASS1    | 0.5 

Table2
   Item|Class
   -----------------------
   ITEM1 | CLASS1
   ITEM2 | CLASS1
   ITEM3 | CLASS1
   ITEM4 | CLASS1
```

Now because the ratio is directly defined for Item1, Item2 at the same level I will not inherit from CLASS1 for both the items even though I have ratio at CLASS level, and for ITEM3, I need to take it from CLASS1.

so expected output is

```
 ITEM | RATIO
 ------------
 ITEM1 | 0.3
 ITEM2 | 0.4 
 ITEM3 | 0.5
 ITEM4 | 0.5
```

Can anyone help me with an optimistic approach to do this is oracle? The logic that I am doing now is to explode the class level entries to item level where item-specific entries are not available and load them along with item level entries into a temporary table and use it in subsequent code. But want to see if there is an effective way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this with two left joins, one to the item level, the other to the class level, and use `COALESCE` to pick the first one that is not null.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (lev VARCHAR2(6), levval VARCHAR2(6), ratio NUMBER);
INSERT INTO  table1
SELECT 'ITEM' , 'ITEM1' , 0.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM' , 'ITEM2' , 0.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLASS', 'CLASS1', 0.5 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (item VARCHAR2(6), class VARCHAR2(6));
INSERT INTO  table2
SELECT 'ITEM1', 'CLASS1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM2', 'CLASS1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM3', 'CLASS1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM4', 'CLASS1' FROM DUAL;
```

With two left joins, both item and class level are tried out. If nothing found, null is displayed:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table2 t2
  LEFT JOIN table1 ti ON t2.item  = ti.levval and ti.lev='ITEM'
  LEFT JOIN table1 tc ON t2.class = tc.levval and tc.lev='CLASS'

ITEM  CLASS  LEV  LEVVAL RATIO LEV_1 LEVVAL_1 RATIO_1
ITEM1 CLASS1 ITEM ITEM1  0.3   CLASS CLASS1   0.5
ITEM2 CLASS1 ITEM ITEM2  0.4   CLASS CLASS1   0.5 
ITEM3 CLASS1 null null   null  CLASS CLASS1   0.5 
ITEM4 CLASS1 null null   null  CLASS CLASS1   0.5
```

Now you select the first one with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT item, COALESCE(ti.ratio, tc.ratio) AS ratio
  FROM table2 t2
  LEFT JOIN table1 ti ON t2.item  = ti.levval and ti.lev='ITEM'
  LEFT JOIN table1 tc ON t2.class = tc.levval and tc.lev='CLASS';

ITEM   RATIO
ITEM1  0.3
ITEM2  0.4
ITEM3  0.5
ITEM4  0.5
```

EDIT:

If you want to speed up things, I'd split table1 into two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE itemratios (
  levval VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL, 
  ratio  NUMBER      NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT itemratio_uq UNIQUE (levval, ratio)
);

INSERT INTO itemratios (levval, ratio) 
SELECT levval, ratio FROM table1 WHERE lev='ITEM';

CREATE TABLE classratios (
  levval VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL, 
  ratio  NUMBER      NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT classratio_uq UNIQUE (levval, ratio)
);

INSERT INTO classratios (levval, ratio) 
SELECT levval, ratio FROM table1 WHERE lev='CLASS';

BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(null, 'table2');
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(null, 'itemratios');
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(null, 'classratios');
END;
/
```

Milage may vary, but the new query is potentially faster:

```
SELECT item, COALESCE(itemratios.ratio, classratios.ratio) AS ratio
  FROM table2 
  LEFT JOIN itemratios  ON table2.item  = itemratios.levval
  LEFT JOIN classratios ON table2.class = classratios.levval;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. As a followup, I have one more question. Assume if I have millions of records, is it recommended to refer same table twice with left join and do `coalesce` or better to explode and maintain all the data in one singe temporary table?

Comment: @Sandeep: Yes, you can speed it up by splitting table1 into two tables, one for item, one for class. Still two joins, but each one is smaller. And put a primary key or two-column unique index on those tables (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ixx ON itemtable (level_value, ratio)...), so Oracle can join the index, not the lookup table.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, the table1 cannot be split into 2. I just need to gather stats and use the same table 2 times with coalese.

Comment: Can you add an index to table1?

Comment: Yes, I can add.

Comment: Then please try if adding an unique index on the 3 columns in the order level, level_value, ratio speeds things up.

Comment: I cannot add on those 3. I have 2 more columns in table1 and the primary key is level+level_value+2 more columns. The 5th column is the ratio.